# Derivative: Find a quadratic polynomial such that $f(1)=5$ , $f′(1)=3$ and $f''(1)=−6$ .

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I'm so confused by this question, so if someone could explain what it is asking and how to solve it step by step, it would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

By calculating the Taylor series expansion of the quadratic about $x=1$ we can say that
$$f(x)=f(1)+f'(1)(x-1)+\frac12f''(1)(x-1)^2$$
as higher order derivatives evaluate to zero. This gives us
$$f(x)=5+3(x-1)-3(x-1)^2=-3x^2+9x-1$$

Answer (score 3):

Say $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$, which is a general quadratic polynomial,

so $f'(x)=2ax+b$ and $f''(x)=2a$.

Then $f(1)=a+b+c=5$, $f'(1)=2a+b=3$, and $f''(1)=2a=-6$.

Can you now solve for $a, b, $ and $c$?